# why the flutter public repo enumn must using as words to import

Tags: flutter, dart

I define a enum in public repo like this in flutter:

```
enum Result {
  ok,
  error,
}
```

then export the enum in root of the repo file like this:

```
export 'src/net/rest/result.dart';
```

in another repo, I want to use this enum, import the enum like this:

```
import 'package:wheel/src/net/rest/result.dart';
```

But I could not use the enum, I must change the import like this:

```
import 'package:wheel/src/net/rest/result.dart' as Result;
```

and use the enum like this `Result.Result.ok`, why could not use it directly? what should I do to use it directly?

Comment: What you did should work.  Are you sure you can't use the `Result.ok` directly?  What happens?  Also, it looks like your other repo is importing the `src/` file directly instead of importing the file with the `export` statement, which is bad style.

Comment: I am sure I could not use the `Result.ok` directly. I also tried to remove the src directly import and only use the root import, still did not work. @jamesdlin

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Is this your exact code?  Can you provide a reproducible example?  I'm inclined to think that you have a name collision with `Result`, although that wouldn't explain why `as Result` would help.

Comment: It may be package conflict, the result is too popular and already defined in other package, so have to using the as keywords. @jamesdlin